# Load multiple files from assembly and convert each one to byte

Tags: c#

I am loading a resource from the current assembly as follows:

```
var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

using (StreamReader str = new StreamReader(a.GetManifestResourceStream("AS.S.sql"))) {

}
```

However I need to read 20 files from the assembly and convert each stream to Byte[].

What is the best way to do this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

foreach (String f in a.GetManifestResourceNames()) {        
  using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(a).GetManifestResourceStream(f))) {
    var file = stream.BaseStream.ToByte();
  }
}
```

Thank You,
Miguel